# Log output too verbose - how to change log level?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I'm trying to debug my simple Rails app and find navigating and printing with puts works well but the log in Bash is way too verbose. I've looked through lots of questions/responses here and have tried some of them but without success. I tried importing the quiet_assets Gem with

```
gem 'quiet_assets', group: :development
```

and have tried changing log levels to :error in production.rb

```
  config.log_level = Logger::error
```

But I still get all the GET requests of Assets when navigating making review of logs difficult.

Worth noting I've tried restarting the server and ran bundle just in case. I did hard refresh even though browser cache shouldn't have anything to do with this.

Here's example navigation:

```
20:08:55 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Oct/2014 20:08:55] "GET /application.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0185
20:08:55 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Oct/2014 20:08:55] "GET /application.css HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0790
20:08:56 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Oct/2014 20:08:56] "GET /brands/46 HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0111
20:08:56 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Oct/2014 20:08:56] "GET /application.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0062
20:08:56 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Oct/2014 20:08:56] "GET /application.css HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0066
20:08:57 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Oct/2014 20:08:57] "GET /brands/46 HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0105
20:08:57 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Oct/2014 20:08:57] "GET /application.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0056
20:08:57 web.1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Oct/2014 20:08:57] "GET /application.css HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0063
20:09:13 web.1  | E, [2014-10-22T20:09:13.695412 #5880] ERROR -- : worker=0 PID:5916 timeout (16s > 15s), killing
20:09:13 web.1  | E, [2014-10-22T20:09:13.704183 #5880] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 5916 SIGKILL (signal 9)> worker=0
20:09:13 web.1  | I, [2014-10-22T20:09:13.710805 #5923]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
```

Comment: `config.log_level = :error`

Comment: it seems you are seeing production log, are you? if that is the case quiet_assets should be included in production too.

Comment: Yes! That certainly did the trick getting quiet_assets to work! I still see a single GET request logged per navigation but can navigate around that. Thanks @juanpastas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are seeing production log, are you? if that is the case quiet_assets should be included in production too.

```
gem 'quiet_assets'
```